# My jQuery map snippet fails in 3.0 but works in 2.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get to the bottom of an error I'm getting with a jQuery map snippet. This works under jQuery 2, but upgrading to 3 it breaks and I'm not sure why. Stuck :/

```js
var menuItems = $("#topNav a");

var scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
  var item = $($(this).attr("href")); // <= this is the culprit ??
  if (item.length) {
    return item;
  }
});

// Expecting an object containing  the page sections
console.log(scrollItems);
```

```html
<!-- THIS FAILS (jQuery 3) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<!-- THIS WORKS HOWEVER (JQuery 2) -->
<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

<!-- My navigation -->
<nav id="topNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<-- My Page sections -->
<div id="page">
  <div id="about">
    <h2>About Us</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="services">
    <h2>Services</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="contact">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you doing `$($(this).attr("href"));` instead of  `$(this).attr("href");`?

Comment: @j08691 because he wants to select the element with the `id` provided by the `href` of the clicked element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your first `<a>` element. This has a `href` of `#`, which results in `$('#')` which (quite rightly) makes the Sizzle selector engine throw an error. Why jQuery 2.x isn't throwing an exception for this is a mystery as it probably should be.

To fix the immediate problem you can exclude that value from the `map()`:

```js
var menuItems = $("#topNav a");

var scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('href') == '#')
    return null;

  var item = $($(this).attr('href'));
  if (item.length) {
    return item;
  }
}).get();

// Expecting an object containing  the page sections
console.log(scrollItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<nav id="topNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="page">
  <div id="about">
    <h2>About Us</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="services">
    <h2>Services</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="contact">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You saved the day. Thanks for that!